# Django REST - Updating or Creating object with foreign key reference

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

`Document` is the parent Model and `LineItem` is the child model with a foreign key reference to `Document`

I am able to delete LineItem individually. However, I am unable to create or update individual LineItem as I keep getting a `ValidationError` stating `'document': [ErrorDetail(string='This field is required.', code='required')`

I have found a few workarounds but am wondering if there is a more standard way to solve this that I maybe overlooking

```
class Document(models.Model):
    """
    ORM representing Document object
    """
    id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True,
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='documents',
    )

class LineItem(models.Model):
    """
    ORM representing line items in a document.
    """

    id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True,
    )
    document = models.ForeignKey(
        Document,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='line_items',
    )
    description = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        blank=True,
        db_default='',
        default='',
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='line_items',
    )
```

**serializers.py**

```
class LineItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = LineItem
        fields = '__all__'
```

**urls.py**

```
 # Add a document line item
    path('api/document/<int:doc_pk>/line/', DocumentLineItemCreateAPI.as_view(), name='document-line-item-add-api'),

    # Edit a document line item
    path('api/document/<int:doc_pk>/line/<int:pk>/', DocumentLineItemUpdateAPI.as_view(), name='document-line-item-update-api'),
```

**views.py**

```
class DocumentLineItemUpdateAPI(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    """
    Unified view for retreiving, updating or deleting document line items
    """
    serializer_class = LineItemSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return LineItem.objects.all()
    
    def get_object(self):
        obj = get_object_or_404(self.get_queryset(), \
                                document_id=self.kwargs.get('doc_pk'), id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return obj
    
    def destroy(self, request, doc_pk, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
           
    def update(self, request, doc_pk, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().update(request, doc_pk, pk, *args, **kwargs)
```

So, the destroy method works fine as expected but the update method throws the error as stated above.

If I modify the Serializer class to explicitly set the `document` field, it works. However I feel that there should be a better way to update Foreign Key fields.
Similarly, the create method also fails and if I modify the Serializer class to explicitly set the document_id from request URL it works.

```
class LineItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    document = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_document(self, obj):
        doc_id = self.context.get('request').parser_context.get('kwargs').get('doc_pk')
        return Document.objects.get(pk=doc_id) 

    def create(self, validated_data):
        doc_id = self.context.get('request').parser_context.get('kwargs').get('doc_pk')
        validated_data['document_id'] = doc_id
        return super().create(validated_data)

    class Meta:
        model = LineItem
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I think you have to explicitly defined in `serializer.py` to handle document id on `create` and `update`. changes again and again might effect  stability of your database and existing data too.

Comment: I do understand that for nested creates and updates we have to explicitly specify the methods. But this is not a nested write - do I still need to explicitly set foreign keys?

Comment: Design matter because when we design an API we made our component according to design, if design is not available then you can pass whole object or you can pass FK, its your choice